# Networking issue using Hashicorp Otto on Ubuntu running on vmware?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, deployment, vagrant, digital-ocean

I am running the following:

- Ubuntu 15.05 ("Wily")
- Virtual Box 5.0.8
- Vagrant 1.7.4
- Otto 0.1.2

All seems to have installed fine after I followed [How to install Hashicorp's Otto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6b5IRVz76do) tutorial.

However, each time I run `otto dev` my internet connection seems to go down (meaning I get a little notify box in my right top corner that tells me that a connection has been established and I'm connected to `vboxnet0` and then it tells me my ethernet connection is disconnected) and I get the following error:

> pc@pc:~/development/my-rails-app$ otto dev
>
> ==> Creating local development environment with Vagrant if it doesn't exist...
>       Raw Vagrant output will begin streaming in below. Otto does
>       not create this output. It is mirrored directly from Vagrant
>       while the development environment is being created.
>
> Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
>
> ==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise64' is up to date...
>
> ==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
>
> ==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
>
> ==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
>       default: Adapter 1: nat
>       default: Adapter 2: hostonly
>
> ==> default: Forwarding ports...
>       default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
>
> ==> default: Booting VM...
>
> ==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
>   The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
>   to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
>   'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured
>   properly and try again.
>
> If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
>   it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
>   GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
>   For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
>   VirtualBox GUI is open.
>
> The primary issue for this error is that the provider you're using
>   is not properly configured. This is very rarely a Vagrant issue.
>
> Error building dev environment: Error executing Vagrant: exit status 1
>
> The error messages from Vagrant are usually very informative.
>   Please read it carefully and fix any issues it mentions. If
>   the message isn't clear, please report this to the Otto project.
>   pc@pc:~/development/my-rails-app$

Any ideas? Is this a problem with using otto on a virtual machine?

Comment: otto is a branch new tool, just announced dew weeks ago, you're better off using the official support from hashicorp to get support

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Otto, but I had a similar error.  The cause of this error in my case:  I **first attempted to set up in Vagrant**, i.e. created a vagrantfile, than attempted to run Otto.

My Vagrantfile was using an ubuntu image, but it was different from the image Otto was trying to use when guessing at my app structure.  Since Otto is supposed to be the tool to abstract Vagrant (and others), I figured I would let it do the work.  So deleting my Vagrantfile solved the issue for me - basically, the two vagrantfiles were conflicting.

You can go in and customize your vagrantfile and otto appfile etc., but this got me up and running.

Answer (score 0):

there was a change in wily64 to rename the ethernet devices from eth0 to a more standardized one, which could lead to disconnecting on bootup.

Eventually this can help you:
https://gist.github.com/brbsix/b70413dec907906ef659

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not a networking issue but VMware misconfiguration.

Vagrant (VirtualBox) will complain if the `vmx` flag is not visible to the guest OS. You need to make sure `cat /proc/cpuinfo |grep vmx` is not be empty.

If you are using VMware Player then turn the vm off, go to Virtual Machine Settings, Processors and enable Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI.